# How to use an angular module that does not support Universal with an angular/cli app using SSR

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal, angular2-aot

Hey everyone I have been building an Angular app that is using Universal with SSR for a while not and every so often I would include a module that would cause the server to fail silently and never knew why, last night I figured out it was because the module I tried to include (ngx-editor) does not support Universal.

Is there a way for me to include a module such as ngx-editor that does not support Universal in my application? Or do I have to find one that supports Universal?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try not calling this module's components depending on the platform, e.g. by checking the platform dynamically in your code ( https://angular.io/api/common/isPlatformBrowser)

```
import {isPlatformBrowser} from "@angular/common";
//...
constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object)
{
 if(isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId))
 {
   //call module's methods/components...
 }
 else { /*server side*/ }
}
```

You may also need to modify your server module (`app.server.module.ts)` to not include modules that do not support angular-universal